# Scss compile error in jekyll does not show what line the error is in

Tags: sass, jekyll

I've trying to convert simple twitter bootstraps bootstrap.css to bootstrap.scss. But I'm getting this error

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error 
converting'css/bootstrap.scss'.
Conversion error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "}"
```

Is there some way to make jekyll tell me the line this error/errors is in or any other way I could track it down.

I tried just to look through everything by hand, but the file is just too massive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just found a site called http://csslint.net/  and just copied all of my bootstrap scss file into it and it found the error line.

I'm still confused why it did not show me this in jekyll, as I can see it in the error messages on other posts on stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry, I can only accept my own answer in two days, so i cannot close the question.